# How to find the smallest value of a parameter that leads to a specific function output

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am trying to calculate the robustness region of a Bayes factor in Matlab in the most efficient way possible. 
In non-Bayesian specific terms, I have a function which takes an input A, and returns output B. I need to find: (1) the smallest A for which B is equal or greater than 3, and (2) the largest A for which B is equal or greater than 3.

Right now, I have a for loop that cycles through a sequence of values for A, and after that I find the smallest and largest As that fulfil the above condition. It works, but it is definitely not the most efficient way to do this, and I have not found any information online so far.

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can start with min and find.  E.g.,

```
Bidx = find( B >= 3 );
[minval, mindix] = min( A(Bidx) )
```

This assumes A and B are the same size.